# get mapping of points with R package TSdist

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the R package TSdist to play around with some of its time series distance measures.
I can get the distance no problem.

```
library(TSdist)

data(example.series3)
data(example.series4)

dtwDistance(example.series3, example.series4)
```

But I'd like to also know how the two series were mapped, and possibly follow with a chart of the the two series and their mapping. How could I do that? I'm looking for something like what you'd get from the package dtw (but dtw is not the answer because I want to use metrics in TSdist that are not available in dtw).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *TSdist* library is based on the *dtw* library and the documentation says that all the functionalities of the *dtw* function are also avaible when using *TSdist* function. As such, when you use the *DTWDistamce function*, I guess that this function is using the path mapped by the *dtw function* of the *dtw* library. Maybe you can directly use the *dtw function* (from dtw lib) to know the mapped path.

Other way is to implement your metric in *dtw* using the argument **dist.method**. If **dist.method** is a string, x and y are passed to the *proxy::dist()* function in package proxy with the method given. If **dist.method** is a function of two arguments, it invoked repeatedly on all pairs x[i],y[j]
to build the local cost matrix.

I hope I could be of help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).